# Can I ask 'where is it now' questions?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a question about the present day location of a ship from the 1800's. Is this sort of question on topic here?

also, I ddint see a /faq page, is that common of a beta.sx site?

Answer (score 3):

I would say "*what is the fate of this ship*" is entirely on topic. The difference between that and "*where is it now*" is probably mostly semantics. Unless you literally want to know where the metal from a ship sold for scraps is currently, or something like that.

Comment: semantics are very important to some...

Answer (score 0):

If you already know all the historical information about a ship, it's probably out of scope. If you are asking about historical details about a ship or identifying a ship from historical records, I believe that's in scope.

The scope page for stack exchanges is not immediately apparent:

1. Click the help drop down from the top menu bar of the site.
2. Click Help Center
3. Click *"[What topics can I ask about here?](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)"* link

In theory the *"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"* link would also be informative, but in practice most stacks have left that one as generic boiler plate.

Comment: Well I certainly do not know **all** of the info about the ship, else I wouldnt be asking about it's presumable ending... I'm not sure where my question would fall into the link you provided for on topic questions... So far, it has gotten a nice reception but no correct answer.